# Installing uwsgi with plugins using 'pip'

Tags: python, pip, uwsgi

I installed uwsgi using `pip install uwsgi`.

When I run uwsgi, I get a couple of errors. The command I'm running is `uwsgi --master --emperor /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled --die-on-term --uid www-data --gid www-data`.

It appears that I'm missing the http and python plugins:

```
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from component_tracking_test.ini
open("./http_plugin.so"): No such file or directory [core/utils.c line 3347]
!!! UNABLE to load uWSGI plugin: ./http_plugin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory !!!
open("./python_plugin.so"): No such file or directory [core/utils.c line 3347]
!!! UNABLE to load uWSGI plugin: ./python_plugin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory !!!
[emperor] removed uwsgi instance component_tracking_test.ini
```

How do I install the required plugins given that I have installed uwsgi via pip?

Comment: NOTE: I'm aware that debian has its own wsgi packages, but they fail to install for some reason. I'm trying pip to avoid having to use the debian packages.

Comment: When I install uwsgi using pip, the compile line contains `-DUWSGI_DECLARE_EMBEDDED_PLUGINS` with python and http among them. Is your configuration actively trying to load them without needing them?

Answer (score 1):

When I add "--binary-path /usr/local/bin/uwsgi" (change path to your wsgi bin) to the command, the error went away.

from the [docu](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html)

> binary-path
>   Argument: string
>
> Force binary path.
>
> If you do not have uWSGI in the system path you can force its path with this option to
>   permit the reloading system and the Emperor to easily find the binary to execute.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar problem and the reason was that I was running `sudo uwsgi`, not realizing that `sudo` won't respect the `PATH` and will launch the system-wide `uwsgi`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48299983/318964).