# uWSGI: No request plugin is loaded, you will not be able to manage requests

Tags: python, uwsgi

I've loaded uWSGI v 1.9.20, built from source.  I'm getting this error, but how do I tell which plugin is needed?

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!! WARNING !!!!!!!!!!!!!!
no request plugin is loaded, you will not be able to manage requests.
you may need to install the package for your language of choice, or simply load
it with --plugin.
!!!!!!!!!!! END OF WARNING !!!!!!!!!!
```

Which plugin should be loaded?

Comment: how have you built uWSGI ? it is pretty uncommon to build using a profile without a specific language (unless you are making a distro package)

Comment: I'm trying to compile uWSGI, then separately compile explicit Python plugins so that I can use multiple Python versions. When doing it like this, not enough plugins are built it seems, so I need to know the list of typical plugins.  It looks like the .ini files in /buildconf give a clue to that.

Comment: This error message really could me more helpful.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I had this problem and was stuck for hours.

#### Python2

My issue is different than the answer listed, make sure you have `plugins = python` in your uwsgi `.ini` file and you install the `uwsgi python` plugin:

```sh
sudo apt-get install uwsgi-plugin-python
```

#### Python3

If you're using Python3, use the same approach and do:

```sh
sudo apt-get install uwsgi-plugin-python3
```

then add `plugins = python3` inside your uwsgi `.ini` file.

---

After I did the above my application worked. Obviously this is for `python` projects, but a similar approach is required for other projects.

Comment: just putting `plugins = python` into the ini sorted this out.

Comment: `plugins = python3` in the uwsgi vassal .ini file if your using the python3 plugin that is, you can `ls /usr/lib/uwsgi/plugins/` to get a list of valid plugin names, minux the _plugin... suffix.

Comment: Fun fact having `plugin = python3` in the configuration without having the plugin installed on the system will not complain about the missing plugin :/ (Thanks)

Answer (score 7):

It might be easiest to install uwsgi through pip instead of the package manager from the OS you're using, the package in pip is usually more up to date than the package managers from the OS you might be using:

```
sudo pip install uwsgi
```

This solved it for me anyway.

For using multiple Python versions on the same server, I would advice to take a look at virtualenv:
https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/

Comment: In my case I already had Debian's version of uwsgi installed before I installed pip's, so I had to make sure to create a symbolic link from /usr/bin/uwsgi to /usr/bin/local before it worked properly.

Answer (score 3):

if you are using python3:

**install plugin:**

```
sudo apt install uwsgi-plugin-python3
```

**add uwsgi python3 plugin line in your site config (.ini file):**

```
plugins = python3
```

and if you want to list your uwsgi's python plugins list:

```
ls -l /usr/lib/uwsgi/plugins/ | grep python
```

**KEEP IN MIND python3 plugin is different from python2.**

If you do not define python's plugin uwsgi says:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!! WARNING !!!!!!!!!!!!!!
no request plugin is loaded, you will not be able to manage requests.
you may need to install the package for your language of choice, or simply load it with --plugin.
!!!!!!!!!!! END OF WARNING !!!!!!!!!!
```

if you use python2's plugin and your venv is in python3 it says:

```
ImportError: No module named site
```

Answer (score 2):

Just stumbled upon this error message and wasted a couple of hours, yet in my case the cause was different from everything mentioned in other answers already.

Suppose you just installed a local uWSGI version via `pip` into your own virtualenv (e.g. as described [here](https://serverfault.com/a/633633/251733)).

Suppose you are now trying to run your uWSGI server as root (because you want to serve the app as `www-data` user, for example). This is how you would do it, right?

```
. venv/bin/activate
sudo uwsgi --ini your-app.ini
```

Wrong! Even though your local `uwsgi` is in your path after you activated your environment, *this path is not passed into the `sudo` command*, and you are launching the system `uwsgi` rather than your local one, which may be the source of endless confusion, like it was in my case.

So, the solution in my case was to simply specify the full path:

```
sudo /full/path/to/venv/bin/uwsgi --ini your-app.ini
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue but this solved it (btw, I use MacOs, and both python2&3 versions installed, but I wanted to use Python3):

- Open terminal and check for python3 location by typing:

> which python3

- Copy the full path and assign it to; **plugins** option in **.ini** file

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you've followed all the python plugin installation steps and **`uwsgi --plugin-list`** still fails to list **`0: python`** as one of the plugins, try restarting your computer. My uwsgi instance ran as a service (from Bash, use **`service status-all`** to see running services) and probably the updated config settings were loaded on service restart.

Answer (score -1):

On my side, this is because instead of having `[uwsgi]` as the header of my configuration inside `/etc/uwsgi/apps-available/`, I put something else (the name of the app).